# On the use of PHP json_encode for an array

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, json

```
$cnt = 0;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    $arre[$cnt]['id'] = $row['idevents'];
    $arre[$cnt]['title'] = $row['title'];
    $arre[$cnt]['start'] = "new Date(" . $row['start'] . "*1000)";
    $arre[$cnt]['end'] = "new Date(" . $row['end'] . "*1000)";
    $arre[$cnt]['allDay'] = $row['allday'];
    $arre[$cnt]['url'] = $row['url'];
    $cnt++;
}


$year = date('Y');
$month = date('m');

echo json_encode(array(

array(
    'id' => 111,
    'title' => "Event1",
    'start' => "$year-$month-10",
    'url' => "http://yahoo.com/"
),

array(
    'id' => 222,
    'title' => "Event2",
    'start' => "$year-$month-20",
    'end' => "$year-$month-22",
    'url' => "http://yahoo.com/"
)

));

?>
```

The json_encode at the bottom of the script is a sample. I need to take the data inside of $arre and json_encode. The format of the json_encode will need to remain pretty much exactly the same as it is otherwise the program may find it not palatable and my program will not work. Does anyone know what the proper code technique would look like here?

Thank You!

Comment: `json_encode` cannot make it javascript for you, your `new Date()`'s will have to be `eval`ed javascript sided. If you need it, you might have to manually create your own and skip `json_encode`.

Comment: Please describe the actual (specific) problem you are having with the above code, and which element of it you are looking for advice about. This question may be better suited to [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, but why can't you just use `json_encode($arre)`

Comment: Looking at your other questions, `json_encode` will return valid JSON.  The issue is that your array (`$arre`) doesn't contain the data you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the correct format to use json_encode() to return arrays to your function, heres an example. Use key value pairs to access the different members:

Also, use an associative array so that you can iterate over the elements on the client side by the names of their columns, not the integer value.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    $thisRow = array(
                     'id'     => $row['idevents'],
                     'title'  => $row['title'],
                     'start'  => date("F j, Y, g:i a", strtotime($row['start'])),
                     'end'    => date("F j, Y, g:i a", strtotime($row['end'])),
                     'allDay' => $row['allday'],
                     'url'    => $row['url']
    );
    array_push($arre, $thisRow);
}

return json_encode(
    array(
        "result" => "success", 
        "data" => $arre
    )
);
```

Then in your javascript/jquery:

```
$.post("myPost.php", post_data,
    function(data) {
        // store data.result;
        // store data.data;
    }, 
"json");
```

Comment: This is most helpful. I'm very much looking forward to applying these tactics. Thank you kindly.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you're doing with the 2 dates. If you elaborate in your original post I can help you update. In my code above, I just formatted the 2 strings from the query into the standard date format.